# Question about table in Credit Lines as Insurance: Evidence from Bangladesh

Tags: microeconomics, behavioral-economics

I am reading a paper for a seminar, titled "[Credit Lines as Insurance: Evidence from
Bangladesh](https://www.gregoryvlane.com/pdfs/JMP_Lane.pdf)" authored by Gregory Lane.

In there, he describes part of his result refering to a table with the following words: "Households that knew they were eligible for the loan increased the amount of land they rented by 30%, and overall cultivation by 15%."

But when I look at the table, I find no 0,30 or 0.15 values, but completely different. I wonder, if I lack certain statistics knowledge, but I don't know where to look it up.

Any hint is highly appreciated

cheers

[image]

Comment: Hi @JohnBlue. I think it's because units of land are defined in acres.

Comment: Hi! You included an image of Table 7, but the quoted sentence seems to be about Table 1.

Comment: You probably need to include more details for the question to be answerable: The regression equation and an explanation of the variables, and what "eligible for the loan" means w.r.t. the regression.